# What's the difference between object destructuring and normal object assignment in Javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

What's the difference between this two code examples (besides the syntax of course)?

### EXAMPLE 1:

```
var user = {
   name: 'Diego',
   age: 25
}

var {name} = user;

console.log(name); // Diego
```

### EXAMPLE 2:

```
var user = {
   name: 'Diego',
   age: 25
}

var name = user.name;

console.log(name); // Diego
```

Both examples assign the same value. I don't get what's the difference or vantage/advantage of using either.

Comment: Destructuring is a handy shortcut when you have an object that contains many other things, and you want to "pull out" many values at once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's extend this to multiple properties:

```
var {foo, bar, baz} = user;
```

In the traditional syntax, this would be:

```
var foo = user.foo,
    bar = user.bar,
    baz = user.baz;
```

So for every property, we have to repeat the object we want to access (`user`) and the name of the property `foo = ... .foo`. The new syntax makes it easier to repeat yourself less.

There's another difference if the object isn't already stored in a variable:

```
var {foo, bar, baz} = getUser();
```

Now we can't just do

```
var foo = getUser().foo,
    bar = getUser().bar,
    baz = getUser().baz;
```

because each call to `getUser` might do different things (due to side effects) or just be inefficient (because we're repeating work). We'd have to create a new local variable to store the object in, just to initialize the three variables we actually care about.

Answer (score 5):

There's no effective difference, but destructuring is convenient:

```
var user = {
   name: 'Diego',
   age: 25
}

var {name, age} = user;
```

That declares and initializes both `name` and `age` in one statement without redundant mentions of the property names.